# Class object variables reads as "undefined" when accessing from the class or class made object from outside the class

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I try to access a class object variable from outside a class it reads as "undefined"

```js
class Foo {
    constructor (arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
        var bar = {
            a: 'Foo'
        }
    }
}
console.log(Foo.bar);
```

But it works if I do it inside the class, but I need it outside the class.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
    var bar = {
      a: 'Foo'
    };
    console.log(bar); //not appearing in the snippet, but it works in a browser
  }
};
```

Comment: In both examples `foo2` is just a variable declared within a function. It's only available within that function's scope and not outside of it. Typically you will use the `constructor` to define properties on the instance object being created (ie: `this`). You can then access it after creating the object using `const obj = new Foo(); obj.foo2`  provided that you added `foo2` as a property to `this` in the constructor. If you want it to be a property of the class, then you can use the [`static` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

Comment: @NickParsons It works, but I have no idea what static does or that it was even in JavaScript.

Comment: The link I’ve included in the comment explains what it does, but its purpose is to add a property to the class instead of the instance created with the “new” keyword.